# MyPy: Can not suppress [no-untyped-call]

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, static-typing

I have been using MyPy python type analysis, I am trying to ignore a specific type warning,

Here is my mypy.ini

```
[mypy]
python_version = 3.9

# Needed because of bug in MyPy
disallow_subclassing_any = False

# Options to make the checking stricter.
check_untyped_defs = True
disallow_untyped_defs = True
disallow_untyped_calls = True

#Plugins
plugins = numpy.typing.mypy_plugin

[mypy-numpy.*]
allow_untyped_defs = True
allow_untyped_calls = True
implicit_reexport = True
```

Here is my sample py code,

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
def test() -> npt.NDArray[np.float32]:
    distance_win: npt.NDArray[np.float32] = np.kron(
        np.ones((10, 1))
        , np.ones((10, 1))
    )
    print (distance_win)
    return distance_win

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (test())
```

When I run the mypy like below,

```
mypy --config-file mypy.ini tests/experiments/py_templ.py
```

I get following output

```
tests\experiments\py_templ.py:32: error: Call to untyped function "kron" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

But, in the ini file , I allow allow_untyped_calls , Why MyPy still complains?

In general I could not get the scoping of the MyPy.ini specification. Please help.

Comment: Its a bug, the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#config-file-format) state that the global options should be overwritten by the per package options which doesn't seem to work for `allow_untyped_calls`. I can only get it to work by changing the global flag.
There is already a [mypy GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10757) on this exact problem.

Comment: (just digged this question accidentally) please kindly note that this is not a bug. It is at most a missing feature, which is not implemented (and never used to be) in `mypy` or other type checkers, AFAIC. `mypy-numpy.*` override suppresses errors within `numpy` module (and you don't typecheck `numpy` itself, do you?), while you want to suppress some errors *related to* `numpy` module. Given that module is not very different from other object, basically you want to disable error for some specific object in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As comments pointed out, the configuration there applied if you type checked the numpy module, not when type checking calls into numpy.

New versions of mypy give you a way to selectively ignore specific untyped calls, see this configuration option: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-untyped-calls-exclude

(Also new versions of numpy have type annotations!)